# Marshmallow URLFor BuildError with ObjectId

Tags: python, rest, flask, mongoengine, hateoas

How can I make my RESTFul API HATEOAS with MongoEngine and Flask-Marshmallow?

I'm using

```
class PraiaSerializer(ma.Schema):                                                                                                      
    id = ma.String()                                                                                                                   
    atividades = ma.Nested(AtividadeSerializer, many=True)                                                                             

    class Meta:                                                                                                                        
        additional = ('nome', 'descricao', '_links')                                                                                   

    _links = ma.Hyperlinks({                                                                                                           
        'self': ma.URLFor('praia_detail', id='<id>'),                                                                                  
        'collection': ma.URLFor('praias')                                                                                              
    })
```

But, when sending a request to my route, marshmallow throws a BuildError.

```
BuildError: ('atividade_detail', MultiDict([('id', ObjectId('55024fdfe138235aeac01380'))]), None)
```

What should I do?

Am I passing something wrong to my `ma.Hyperlinks`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem!

I'm using Flask-RESTFul to write my API, so I had to register my routes with an endpoint name. In case of using pure Flask, use your function names.

```
api.add_resource(PraiaListView, '/v1/praias', endpoint='praias_resource')
api.add_resource(PraiaView, '/v1/praias/<id>', endpoint='praia_detail')
```

and use:

```
_links = ma.Hyperlinks({                                                                                                           
        'self': ma.URLFor('praia_detail', id='<id>'),                                                                                  
        'collection': ma.URLFor('praias_resource')                                                                                              
    })
```

so marshmallow could generate this output for the _links field:

```
"_links": {
  "collection": "/v1/praias",
  "self": "/v1/praias/55025029e138235aeac01383"
},
```

Comment: `ma` is the marshmallow that was instantiated using the app instance!

Something like:
`app = Flask(__name__);
ma = Marshmallow(app)`